# Is there a relevant manual or documentation describing the data storage mode of Revit?

Tags: revit-api, revit

Revit is a data integration software, we can see a lot of model/component information, such as geometric information, material information and so on.

Then inside Revit, there must be something similar to a database, which stores this information, shows it to us, stores geometric information, material information, model mapping information, etc. in the library, and displays them to users when they are used in drawing Look.

The question is coming, how can we see this internal storage mechanism? Is there a relevant manual or documentation describing the data storage mode of Revit?

Comment: Are you using Revit-Lookup Addin?

Comment: Just use Revit API. But I dont know how to find the data schema in Revit

Answer (score 1):

Inside Revit, there is indeed something like a database.

There is no way to directly see or access this internal storage mechanism.

There is therefore no manual or documentation describing it.

One effective way to explore the contents of the Revit database, is via [RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup).

Comment: Yeah！So I have used Lookup during Jul.2020. Thank you for your work!